# Is there a word for "divulging unintentionally"?

Tags: word-request

> The President * information to an unauthorized staff of the White
>   House.

I am wondering if there's a word for divulging unintentionally like as in a person leaking corporate information to a person who's not supposed to have that information unintentionally. Is there such a word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one word option, there's "[blab](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blab)" which means

> to reveal a secret especially by indiscreet chatter

but it's not a particularly formal word--I wouldn't expect to read it in a news article.

I would expect to see something like "let slip."

> He let privileged information slip to an unauthorized member...

If formality isn't an issue at all, there are also variations like "spill the beans."