# Is there an idiom that means "revealing a secret unintentionally"?

Tags: idiom-request

I am thinking there could be an idiom that states that you or someone revealed a secret unintentionally? Can you think of an idiom like that? I am looking for an idiom I can use to write a blog post about the recent incident where Secretary Pompeo unintentionally revealed the dirty secrets behind the CIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a word for "divulging unintentionally"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/207917/is-there-a-word-for-divulging-unintentionally)

Comment: I asked for an idiom, not a word.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Let the cat out of the bag** is the idiomatic answer to this.

Oxford (and google dictionary):  [Reveal a secret carelessly or by mistake.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/let_the_cat_out_of_the_bag)

Edit:  It appears commentators dispute the 'unintentionality' of this phrase.  Further definitions in support:

Dictionary.com: [to divulge a secret, especially inadvertently or carelessly](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/let--the--cat--out--of--the--bag)  `<- scroll down to idioms`

Cambridge:  [to allow a secret to be known, usually without intending to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/let-the-cat-out-of-the-bag)

Collins:  [to disclose a secret, often by mistake](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/let-the-cat-out-of-the-bag)

Comment: Without having a reference: I personally would say that this is the idiom to use when the secret was palpable, like somebody was beating around the bush for a while until they finally let the cat out of the bag. Like junior wants to have the car for the weekend and doesn't dare ask outright.

Comment: Oh, plus it is not necessarily unintentional. Perhaps more often used when the secret was finally revealed intentionally.

Comment: This is actually an idiom, so I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: No, that is just "revealing a secret", but it is not necessarily "unintentionally".

Comment: I've practically only ever heard this expression used when someone intentionally reveals information - not in an accidental way, and am very surprised so many dictionary references include the fact it's done by mistake.  That, in my experience, is seldom how it's used. (Especially compared to @Andrw's answer, which includes "let slip", which is almost always used when something is revealed unintentionally). (...When you take this literally, letting the cat out of a bag is an *intentional* action, lending further credence to it being primarily an active doing, not unintentional...)

Comment: @BruceWayne I agree. Also why does it seem that comments disappear here?

Comment: (@wavery - I assume that's due to a Moderator removing a comment.)

Answer (score 38):

Yes, there are a number which imply "by accident":

> Mike Pompeo **let slip** some of the CIA's secrets.
>
> Mike Pompeo **spilled** some of the CIA's secrets.
>
> Mike Pompeo **let out** some of the CIA's secrets.
>
> Mike Pompeo **blabbed** some of the CIA's secrets.
>
> Mike Pompeo **gave away** some of the CIA's secrets.
>
> Mike Pompeo **blurted out** some of the CIA's secrets.

If you want to be clear, you can always specify that the action was unintentional:

> Mike Pompeo **unwittingly spilled the beans** on some of the CIA's secrets.
>
> Mike Pompeo **inadvertently let the cat out of the bag** on some of the CIA's secrets.

There are others that mean "reveal", but you need to specify whether this was intentional or unintentional:  *divulge, disclose, leak, expose, confess* etc.

> Mike Pompeo **unintentionally divulged** some of the CIA's secrets.
>
> Mike Pompeo **accidentally leaked** some of the CIA's secrets.

and so on.

(Edit) As a few of the comments suggest, all of these verbs can also be used for *intentional* disclosure.  Example:

> Mike Pompeo may have **deliberately let slip** some of the CIA's secrets.

I just feel the ones in the first part, by default, sound unintentional.   By making them intentional it adds the nuance of *duplicity* -- which is to say, the subject is only *pretending* to "accidentally" reveal some information.

Still, opinions on this will vary from person to person.

Comment: Don't forget "Let the cat out of the bag"

Comment: Blabbed seems the closest to what OP is driving at. I'm assuming this is a hit-piece on Pompeo rather than something more nuanced.

Comment: @Richard  Sure, if they're trying to imply that Pompeo **runs his mouth**, a poor character trait for a spymaster.

Comment: I think the key here is the inclusion of `unintentionally`, `inadvertently`, `unwittingly`, or `accidentally` (or other appropriate synonym). Without those, any of the statements could be taken to mean he did so intentionally.

Comment: @asgallant: "let slip" definitely means it was accidental/inadvertent unless there is a specific context that push it towards a meaning of "intentionally, but coyly" (I checked several dictionaries, and the accidental/inadvertent/unintentional aspect is part of the definition, not merely a connotation I'm inferring from local usage). I agree that the rest of them require more effort to make the release inadvertent; by default, they either imply intent or don't imply anything one way or the other.

Comment: "Spilled the Beans" is another idiom that comes to mind.

Comment: "Blabbed" can very much imply intentional revelation. As can "gave away."

Comment: @JonathanS - "Spilled the beans" could also be used for intentionally revealing secrets, though.

Comment: I think 'let slip' is the only example definitely showing unintentionality, 'blurted' is a maybe.  'Blabbed' and 'gave away' sound like they're definitely intentional to my ear.

Comment: I wouldn't describe most of those as "idioms".

Comment: To my AmE ear, "spilled the beans" implies accident (as one does not usually spill intentionally).

Comment: This is more accurate than the accepted answer - which may be defined in dictionaries as 'often by mistake', but adding those words, or similar, is the defining moment. Cat = cat-o'-nine-tails, kept in bag on ships, used as discipline. When cat is out, the result is fairly obvious, so it wouldn't happen by accident. Probably.

Comment: @Tim I thought "let the cat out of the bag" was related to the expression "a pig in a poke", whereby at, say, a country market in past times, an unscruprulous trader would pretend to sell piglets in a bag (i.e a poke) to unwary customers only to find, later, that it actually contained a cat.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_in_a_poke

Comment: @SimonF - you are right, I think. I'll check it out and possibly delete!